# Set Seaborn PairGrid x-axis with 2 different value ranges

Tags: python, seaborn

[The resolution is described below.]

I'm trying to create a PairGrid. The X-axis has at least 2 different value ranges, although even when 'cvar' below is plotted by itself the x-axis overwrites itself.

My question: is there a way to tilt the x-axis labels to be vertical or have fewer x-axis labels so they don't overlap? Is there another way to solve this issue?

====================

```
import seaborn as sns

import matplotlib.pylab as plt

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

columns = ['avar', 'bvar', 'cvar']
index = np.arange(10) 
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, index = index)

myarray = np.random.random((10, 3))

for val, item in enumerate(myarray):
    df.ix[val] = item

df['cvar'] = [400,450,43567,23000,19030,35607,38900,30202,24332,22322]

fig1 = sns.PairGrid(df, y_vars=['avar'],
                    x_vars=['bvar', 'cvar'],
                    palette="GnBu_d")          
fig1.map(plt.scatter, s=40, edgecolor="white")
# The fix: Add the following to rotate the x axis. 
plt.xticks( rotation= -45 )
```

=====================

The code above produces this image
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: off the top of my head, `fig1.tick_params` (or something like that)

Comment: Thanks. I just tried something similar to tick_params and a few other options on StackOverflow but get the same behavior above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I added "plt.xticks( rotation= -45 )" to the original code above. More can be fund on the MatPlotLib site [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_demo_rotation.html?highlight=xticks%20rotation).